# App Maker- Records appear in multiple pages (Pagging issue)

Tags: google-app-maker

When I create a ticket through call dispatcher role's page, it is created in the third page as there are  three pages of tickets records, but when I go to the Engineer role's page the new assigned ticket appear in the third page and the first two pages is blank.

I think this problem happens because I invisible the tickets resolved by the engineer and I think in this way the tickets remains in its place but invisible.
So I want to appear the new assigned tickets in the Engineer role's at the first one so I think I need to do a Query filter on the records to solve this issue but I don't know how to do it.

If anyone could help with the exact steps for Query filter for example: Engineer specific email or if ticket status="Resolved"

Note: I knew that Appmaker will shut down completely but I need to solve this issue until I transfer into a new platform.

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the records invisible in the Engineer role page?
One way to limit which records show in different pages is to add a new datasource to your database (click on the database and then the datasource tab and Add Datasource) and use a query script to filter results. For example, let's say you need to display tickets assigned to "Engineer", your query would look like:

```
query.filters.AssignedTo._equals = "Engineer";
return query.run();
```

Don't forget to go back to the Engineer page and update the datasource to the newly created one.